Difference between Pressure Jump and Pressure Gradient in multiphase flow, and Relationship between them
Assuming we have a multiphase flow (maybe a bubble immersed in water) with interface separating between the two phases. The interface is defined with a certain surface tension. Due to the liquid properties and surface tension, there will be pressure difference inside and outside of the two phases. I read somewhere about pressure jump $\Delta P$ and pressure gradient $\nabla P$, but did not see clear difference between the two and cannot establish relationship between them. Anyone can help?

In $\nabla P$, P is the pressure averaged over the two phases, weighted in terms of volume.
